# Google Analytics iOS SDK session timeout - User session drastically increasing

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

Facing issue with the iOS daily users and number of sessions data. We are sure that the numbers are spiked. We use these numbers to check our daily and overall conversion rate and make decisions based on them.

One of our observations is that when we send a push notification, then the number is increased more than it is supposed to. Is there any relation between that?

It started happening last October - PFA the data. See a huge change in number of sessions after Sept 2020:

[image]

GoogleAnalytics version 3.0.13, then updated to 3.0.19, but still name issue.

Comment: when the push notification is received by a device (provided user opted-in to receive notifications), the app is invoked, and hence if your stats is based on `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, you will register a push notification as a visit. Hard to say anything else without seeing how exactly you get those numbers, and how timeouts are related to them

Comment: @KirilS: Ya I got your point, may be that is also one reason?, I have initialising GA, let me try by putting condition, In didFinishLaunch, via notification no need to initial GA.
Note :  How come suddenly changing behaviour from Oct 2020. Any major update from GA ->  [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:NSLocalizedString(@"kGOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CLIENTSID", @"")];
    [GAI sharedInstance].logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;
then 
 NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(notification)
    {
     
    }

Comment: In October something very important happened: iOS 15 started rolling out (end of September really, but noticable in October). So most likely it has to do with some changes on new iOS version.

Comment: Yeah iOS 14 has major update on Oct 2020.I will check by updating the some frameworks.because most of them are 2years old one. Meanwhile let me know any other option? I have moved code of GA initialise in didFinishlaunch when app relaunches on notification click.